# Coldfusion date conversion: "2013-11-15T06:11:57.87 is an invalid date or time string"

Tags: coldfusion, date-formatting

I am trying to convert a date from UTC to local and I am getting the following error:
"2013-11-15T06:11:57.87 is an invalid date or time string"

Here is the partial code:

```
#DateFormat(DateConvert("utc2Local", apiResult.Created), 'm/d/yy')#
```

As you have guessed apiResult.Created is  2013-11-15T06:11:57.87

Any ideas?
Thank you

Comment: Looks like some sort of ISO date. A good place to check is cflib.org. A quick search turned up [DateConvertISO8601](http://www.cflib.org/udf/DateConvertISO8601) and also [this link](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/811-Converting-ISO-Date-Time-To-ColdFusion-Date-Time.htm), both of which seem to successfully convert your sample string into a date object which you can use with CF's date functions.

Answer (score 3):

Your problem seems to be that the string `2013-11-15T06:11:57.87` is not a recognised date string format. You're probably going to have to parse it yourself. I found this example for twitter dates which you could probably modify to your needs:

```
<cffunction name="parseTwitterDateFormat" output="false" returntype="String" hint="I return the date in a useable date format.">
  <cfargument name="twitterDate" required="true" type="string" hint="The Twitter date." />
  <cfset var formatter = CreateObject("java", "java.text.SimpleDateFormat").init("EEE MMM d kk:mm:ss Z yyyy") />
  <cfset formatter.setLenient(true) />
  <cfreturn formatter.parse(arguments.twitterDate) />
</cffunction>
```

More info: http://www.petefreitag.com/item/569.cfm

Java Documentation for SimpleDateFormat: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

Based on the Java documentation I think you need the format string: `"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SS"`

Note that I did read a comment stating the SimpleDateFormat class converts the time to local time, you may want to check this.

Comment: I was curious so I tried it with ParseDatetime.  If you lose the letter T and the milliseconds Bob will be your uncle.

Comment: Just be aware of the implications of `setLenient(true)`. When passed an invalid date like February 31, 2013 it will automatically adjust the bad date to March 3rd, rather than throwing an exception because you passed in an invalid date string. Sometimes that behavior desirable. Other times not, so adjust the setting accordingly.