# Coldfusion finding date in an array

Tags: arrays, coldfusion, coldfusion-9

Need help finding a specific date in an array.

I have an Array Populated from a JSON file. Would like a form to enter in a date then return the data if it's in the Array.

This is what I've tried so far.

```
<!---Form and submit button to enter date--->
<p>
    <cfform name="pickdate" id="pickdate" >
        <cfinput required="yes" name="datepicker" type="datefield" id="datepicker" validate="USDATE">
        <cfinput type="submit" name="insertpbnum" value="Enter" id="submit">
    </cfform>
</p>

<br>
<br>
<!---Get lotto numbers from JSON file--->
<cfhttp url="https://data.ny.gov/api/views/d6yy-54nr/rows.json?accessType=DOWNLOAD" method="get" result="httpResp" timeout="120">
    <cfhttpparam type="header" name="Content-Type" value="application/json" />
</cfhttp>
<cfset pbdata=deserializeJSON(httpResp.filecontent)>
<cfoutput>
    <!---loop thru JSON file to grab lotto numbers and dates--->
    <cfloop from="1" to="#arrayLen(pbdata.data)#" index="i">
        <!---change xml date-time format to Coldfusion formate--->
        #arrayFind(datetimeformat(Parsedatetime(pbdata.data[i][9]),"MM-DD-YYYY","datepicker"))#
        <!---#i#: #Parsedatetime(pbdata.data[i][9])#  : #pbdata.data[i][10]#---><br />
    </cfloop>

</cfoutput>
```

I'm I going about this the correct way. Or is it better to put the array into a database?

Thanks

Comment: What happens now when you execute the posted code?

Comment: the string you get in the xml is not convertable to date as is. you might want to parse it yourself. I believe your issue was addressed here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20088433/coldfusion-date-conversion-2013-11-15t061157-87-is-an-invalid-date-or-time-s

Comment: Ignoring the question for a second, based on the evolution of some of your other questions, you may want to take a step back up. First identify a) Which of the fields will your app be using (date, modifier, numbers, ...) and b) *How* will those fields be accessed. For example, will the app search results by date (only), by number(s), etcetera.. Those answers will help in determining how to best store/cache and parse the results.

Answer (score -1):

This is a different approach, but will hopefully accomplish what your trying to do.  This solution throws the data into a query and then performs a query of query (QOQ) to check for the date.

```
<cfhttp url="https://data.ny.gov/api/views/d6yy-54nr/rows.json?accessType=DOWNLOAD" method="get" result="httpResp" timeout="120">
    <cfhttpparam type="header" name="Content-Type" value="application/json" />
</cfhttp>
<cfset pbdata=deserializeJSON(httpResp.filecontent)>

<!--- Get list of column names --->
<cfset columnList = "" />
<cfloop from="1" to="11" index="i">
    <cfset columnList = listAppend(columnList, replace(pbdata.meta.view.columns[i].name, " ", "", "All")) />
</cfloop>

<!--- Populate data into query --->
<cfset qryData = queryNew(columnList) />
<cfset dataRowCount = arrayLen(pbdata.data) />
<cfset queryAddRow(qryData, dataRowCount) />
<cfloop from="1" to="#dataRowCount#" index="i">
    <cfloop from="1" to="#arrayLen(pbdata.data[i])#" index="j">
        <cfif j EQ 11 AND pbdata.data[i][j] EQ "null">
            <!--- default multiplier field to 0 if null --->
            <cfset querySetCell(qryData, listGetAt(columnList, j), 0, i) />
        <cfelse>
            <cfset querySetCell(qryData, listGetAt(columnList, j), pbdata.data[i][j], i) />
        </cfif>
    </cfloop>
</cfloop>

<!--- Query the recordset --->
<cfquery name="rs" dbtype="query">
    SELECT  *
    FROM    qryData
    WHERE   DrawDate = '#dateFormat("5/26/2010", "YYYY-MM-DD")#T00:00:00'
</cfquery>

<cfdump var="#rs#" />
```

Comment: Downvotes without explanations are unhelpful, discourteous, and cowardly.